# Duplication issue with left join only by adding one column

Tags: sql, db2

So I apologize for the wall of code, but I'm losing my mind over this tiny issue that is kicking my butt.  The below query works perfectly and gives me everything I need to see with the exception of one column from DB.ACTIVITY_T.  The moment I add said column, I immediately get duplicates where there is a MNT.ARRIVEDTS present.  I can't seem to figure out why adding one more column to my select statement is causing this duplication.  Maybe I'm too deep into this to see what's right in front of me?  If you see what could be causing the error, please feel free to enlighten me.

```
    SELECT
    TRIM(B.REFNUMBER) AS "REFNUMBER"
    ,DATE(NUM_TSTAMP) AS "P/U DATE"
    ,CASE WHEN DATE(REPORT_TS) IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CHAR(DATE(REPORT_TS)) END AS "DELIVERY DATE"
    ,CASE WHEN REPORT_TS IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS "DELIVERED"
    ,B.WEIGHT AS "WGT"
    ,B.PIECES
    ,B.WANT_DATE
    ,CEIL(B.CUBE) AS "SHPMNT CUBE"
    ,CASE WHEN B.DESTINATION = '5647' THEN 'DERPO'
          WHEN B.DESTINATION = '1234' THEN 'DERPB'
          WHEN B.DESTINATION = '9856' THEN 'DERPC'
          ELSE ''
    END AS "DERP POINT"
    ,CASE WHEN R.REFNO IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CHAR(R.REFNO) END AS "DERP #"
    ,CASE WHEN C.CITY = 'DERPSTON' THEN 'BLAH'
          WHEN C.CITY = 'DERPELVANIA' THEN 'HABD'
          WHEN C.CITY = 'DERPVILLE' THEN 'POIN'
          ELSE ''
    END AS "SEQUENCE"
    ,CASE WHEN E.EVENT_DESCRIPTION = 'ABCD' THEN 'Y' 
          ELSE 'N' 
    END AS "DERP DERP" 
    ,DATE(E.EVENT_TIMESTAMP) AS "DERP DATE"
    ,TIME(E.EVENT_TIMESTAMP) AS "DERP TIME"
    ,CASE WHEN I.DOC_TYPE = 'DERPI' THEN 'Y' 
          ELSE 'N'
    END AS "DERP
    ,CASE WHEN B.CUBE > '0.5' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS "DERP CUBE”
    ,MNT."DERP ARRIVED"

    FROM PQ.MAIN B

    INNER JOIN PQ.MAIN_ALTERNATE A
    ON B.REFNUMBER = A.REFNUMBER
    AND B.CORRECTION = A.CORRECTION
    AND A.NUMBER_KEY = ''

    INNER JOIN PQ.MAIN_NAME C
    ON C.REFNUMBER = B.REFNUMBER
    AND C.CORRECTION = B.CORRECTION
    AND C.TYPE = 'C'
    AND C.NUMBER_KEY = ''
    AND C.NUM_CODE = 'ABCD'

    INNER JOIN PQ.MAIN_NAME S
    ON B.REFNUMBER = S.REFNUMBER
    AND B.CORRECTION = S.CORRECTION
    AND S.TYPE = 'S'
    AND S.COUNTRY = 'US'
    AND S.NUMBER_KEY = ''

    LEFT OUTER JOIN DB.ACTIVITY_NUM MN
    ON MN.REFNUMBER = B.REFNUMBER

    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT MAX(DATE(A.ARRIVEDTS)) AS "DERP ARRIVED", MFSTNBR
    FROM AF.MANIFEST_T A WHERE A.DESTINATION IN ('1234','5647') GROUP BY MFSTNBR) AS MNT
    ON MNT.MFSTNBR = MN.MFSTNBR

    LEFT OUTER JOIN PQ.MAIN_EVENT E
    ON E.REFNUMBER = B.REFNUMBER
    AND E.EVENT_TYPE = 'R'
    AND E.EVENT_DESCRIPTION = 'RANDO'
    AND E.NUMBER_KEY = ''

    LEFT OUTER JOIN DB.DERP_INDEX I
    ON B.REFNUMBER = I.REFNUMBER
    AND I.DOC_TYPE = 'LIE'
    AND PAGE_NUM = '1'
    AND I.INDEX_DATE >= CURRENT DATE - 15 DAYS

    LEFT OUTER JOIN PQ.MAIN_REFNO R
    ON R.REFNUMBER = B.REFNUMBER
    AND R.CORRECTION = B.CORRECTION
    AND REFNO LIKE '%BOOG%'
    AND R.NUMBER_KEY = ''

    WHERE B.NUM_NUM_NUM = '123'
    AND B.DESTINATION IN ('1234','5647','9856')
    AND DATE(B.NUM_TSTAMP) >= CURRENT DATE - 10 DAYS

    GROUP BY 
    TRIM(B.REFNUMBER) 
    ,DATE(NUM_TSTAMP) 
    ,CASE WHEN DATE(REPORT_TS) IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CHAR(DATE(REPORT_TS)) END 
    ,CASE WHEN REPORT_TS IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END
    ,B.WEIGHT
    ,B.PIECES
    ,B.WANT_DATE
    ,CEIL(B.CUBE)
    ,CASE WHEN B.DESTINATION = '5647' THEN 'DERPO'
          WHEN B.DESTINATION = '1234' THEN 'DERPB'
          WHEN B.DESTINATION = '9856' THEN 'DERPC'
          ELSE ''
    END
    ,CASE WHEN R.REFNO IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CHAR(R.REFNO)
    ,CASE WHEN C.CITY = 'DERPSTON' THEN 'BLAH'
          WHEN C.CITY = 'DERPELVANIA' THEN 'HABD'
          WHEN C.CITY = 'DERPVILLE' THEN 'POIN'
          ELSE ''
    END 
    ,CASE WHEN E.EVENT_DESCRIPTION = 'ABCD' THEN 'Y' 
          ELSE 'N' 
    END
    ,DATE(E.EVENT_TIMESTAMP) 
    ,TIME(E.EVENT_TIMESTAMP) 
    ,CASE WHEN I.DOC_TYPE = 'DERPI' THEN 'Y' 
          ELSE 'N'
    END
    ,CASE WHEN B.CUBE > '0.5' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
    ,MNT."DERP ARRIVED"
```

Here are the results that you asked for.

```
   REFNUMBER   DERP ARRIVED    MFSTNBR
   123456789   [null]          [null]
   123456789   [null]          [null]
   123456789   2015-12-15      32304587
   987654321   [null]          [null]
   987654321   [null]          [null]
   987654321   2015-12-13      49304483
```

Each null actually has a different MFSTNBR tied to it, but it's returning a null because it doesn't meet the '1234' or '5647' criteria.  If I remove the destination criteria the nulls would be replaced with similar but different MFSTNBR.

Comment: Just off the cuff I would save you have a cardinality issue.  There must be multiple records in DB_Activity_T  for each record in DB_ACTIVITY_NUM.  You either need to sub query DB.Activity_T to only return those columns you need and group by to eliminate the duplicates or aggregrate more at the outer level, or adjust join criteria to eliminate the duplicates.

Comment: Your first clue that something's wrong is the fact that you're using `GROUP BY`, but have no aggregate functions.  If you really need to de-dup identical records, you want `DISTINCT`.  Note, however, that this will only mask your problem, which is that you're getting unexpected duplicates; it's better to figure out where they're coming from and squash them early.  Especially because you have a _really_ wide key, and the `CASE`s hurt even more.

Comment: Side note: I generally prefer not to nest `OUTER JOIN`s, as you do between `Activity_Num` and `MNT` (the other `LEFT JOIN` tables are fine, since they tie back to an `INNER`).  In many cases the data model will support this.  You can get into weird places logically otherwise.  Also, consider making small, in-query virtual tables (with `VALUES`) for conversion tables (for stuff like translating `B.Destination`), instead of using `CASE`.

Comment: Gonna have to look into this "Also, consider making small, in-query virtual tables (with VALUES) for conversion tables (for stuff like translating B.Destination), instead of using CASE".  I just kinda picked up SQL and never learned in a traditional setting, so this is foreign to me.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you're getting multiple records from MNT when you only want one...

Likely MNT.Destination having 2 different values will result in 2 records for the max, not one.

Replace the

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN DB.ACTIVITY_T MNT
```

with

```
(SELECT MAX(DATE(MNT.ARRIVEDTS)) as "DERP ARRIVED", MFSTNBR
FROM DB.Activity_T
WHERE MNT.DESTINATION IN ('1234','5647')
GROUP BY MFSTNBR) as MNT
```

and eliminate the join critiera;

```
ND MNT.DESTINATION IN ('1234','5647') as it's taken care of by the inline view.
```

oh and modify the select to just look for "DERP ARRIVED" on the top most select.

Just my guess...

```
SELECT
TRIM(B.REFNUMBER) AS "REFNUMBER"
,DATE(NUM_TSTAMP) AS "P/U DATE"
,CASE WHEN DATE(REPORT_TS) IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CHAR(DATE(REPORT_TS)) END AS "DELIVERY DATE"
,CASE WHEN REPORT_TS IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS "DELIVERED"
,B.WEIGHT AS "WGT"
,B.PIECES
,B.WANT_DATE
,CEIL(B.CUBE) AS "SHPMNT CUBE"
,CASE WHEN B.DESTINATION = '5647' THEN 'DERPO'
      WHEN B.DESTINATION = '1234' THEN 'DERPB'
      WHEN B.DESTINATION = '9856' THEN 'DERPC'
      ELSE ''
END AS "DERP POINT"
,CASE WHEN R.REFNO IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CHAR(R.REFNO) END AS "DERP #"
,CASE WHEN C.CITY = 'DERPSTON' THEN 'BLAH'
      WHEN C.CITY = 'DERPELVANIA' THEN 'HABD'
      WHEN C.CITY = 'DERPVILLE' THEN 'POIN'
      ELSE ''
END AS "SEQUENCE"
,CASE WHEN E.EVENT_DESCRIPTION = 'ABCD' THEN 'Y' 
      ELSE 'N' 
END AS "DERP DERP" 
,DATE(E.EVENT_TIMESTAMP) AS "DERP DATE"
,TIME(E.EVENT_TIMESTAMP) AS "DERP TIME"
,CASE WHEN I.DOC_TYPE = 'DERPI' THEN 'Y' 
      ELSE 'N'
END AS "DERP
,CASE WHEN B.CUBE > '0.5' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS "DERP CUBE”
-------Modified the next line--------------
,MNT."DERP ARRIVED"

FROM PQ.MAIN B

INNER JOIN PQ.MAIN_ALTERNATE A
ON B.REFNUMBER = A.REFNUMBER
AND B.CORRECTION = A.CORRECTION
AND A.NUMBER_KEY = ''

INNER JOIN PQ.MAIN_NAME C
ON C.REFNUMBER = B.REFNUMBER
AND C.CORRECTION = B.CORRECTION
AND C.TYPE = 'C'
AND C.NUMBER_KEY = ''
AND C.NUM_CODE = 'ABCD'

INNER JOIN PQ.MAIN_NAME S
ON B.REFNUMBER = S.REFNUMBER
AND B.CORRECTION = S.CORRECTION
AND S.TYPE = 'S'
AND S.COUNTRY = 'US'
AND S.NUMBER_KEY = ''

LEFT OUTER JOIN DB.ACTIVITY_NUM MN
ON MN.REFNUMBER = B.REFNUMBER

-------Modified the next line--------------
LEFT OUTER JOIN     (SELECT MAX(DATE(A.ARRIVEDTS)) as "DERP ARRIVED", MFSTNBR
    FROM DB.Activity_T A
    WHERE A.DESTINATION IN ('1234','5647')
    GROUP BY MFSTNBR) as MNT
ON MNT.MFSTNBR = MN.MFSTNBR
-------Removed this line. the next line--------------
---and MNT.DESTINATION IN ('1234','5647')    -------

LEFT OUTER JOIN PQ.MAIN_EVENT E
ON E.REFNUMBER = B.REFNUMBER
AND E.EVENT_TYPE = 'R'
AND E.EVENT_DESCRIPTION = 'RANDO'
AND E.NUMBER_KEY = ''

LEFT OUTER JOIN DB.DERP_INDEX I
ON B.REFNUMBER = I.REFNUMBER
AND I.DOC_TYPE = 'LIE'
AND PAGE_NUM = '1'
AND I.INDEX_DATE >= CURRENT DATE - 15 DAYS

LEFT OUTER JOIN PQ.MAIN_REFNO R
ON R.REFNUMBER = B.REFNUMBER
AND R.CORRECTION = B.CORRECTION
AND REFNO LIKE '%BOOG%'
AND R.NUMBER_KEY = ''

WHERE B.NUM_NUM_NUM = '123'
AND B.DESTINATION IN ('1234','5647','9856')
AND DATE(B.NUM_TSTAMP) >= CURRENT DATE - 10 DAYS

GROUP BY 
TRIM(B.REFNUMBER)
,DATE(NUM_TSTAMP)
,REPORT_TS
,REPORT_TS
,B.WEIGHT 
,B.PIECES
,B.WANT_DATE
,CEIL(B.CUBE)
,B.DESTINATION
,R.REFNO
,C.CITY
,E.EVENT_DESCRIPTION
,DATE(E.EVENT_TIMESTAMP)
,TIME(E.EVENT_TIMESTAMP)
,I.DOC_TYPE
,B.CUBE
 --- Added this line----
,MNT."DERP ARRIVED"
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I'm gonna try this out tomorrow and see how it works.

Comment: I just finished modifying the query and now I'm getting the duplication without even adding the column which was causing duplication in my unmodified query.  As mentioned previously, the only time there is a duplication is when there is an ARRIVEDTS present from the subquery in the left outer join.  To clarify, there will never be an instance where there is a match to both '12345' and '5647' in the same column.  There are multiple  MFSTNBR's for each line, but that is why i wanted it to return either '1234' or '5647'  hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: If you run this `(SELECT MAX(DATE(A.ARRIVEDTS)) as "DERP ARRIVED", MFSTNBR
    FROM DB.Activity_T A
    WHERE A.DESTINATION IN ('1234','5647')
    GROUP BY MFSTNBR)` notice I did remove the MNT aliases independant of the whole query, you get 1 DERP Arrived for each MFSTNBR correct?

Comment: Same result.  I only get one DERP, but it duplicates the entire line again when there is one DERP, but there is a [null] in the DERP column for the dup.  This doesn't make sense to me why it would create a null DERP anytime it finds one in the previous line...

Comment: I misspoke...wrote.. Does the above query in comment return more than 1 record per MFSTNBR?  If we ever get 2 that's the  problem we need to rectify.  Based on your comment I think it is... as you stated you only get one, but then yous aid it duplicates it again with a DERP of null... if we are getting two records then this is where we need to focus our attention.  I also noticed that your case statements are not contained in your group by and instead you're grouping by the element your casing, try adding ,B.DESTINATION
,R.REFNO
,C.CITY to the select and see if that's causing the duplication.

Comment: The more I look at it the more I think your group by is what's causing the issue here.  Grouping on elements which you're casing to different values.  Try adding the cases statements to the group by instead of just the columns you're casing.

Comment: I am getting duplicates on the MFSTNBR.  I'm going to go back in and modify the group by as you suggested to see what happens there.  I will come back with the results *fingers crossed.

Comment: I made the recommended changes to the group by and the results are still the same.  I edited my first post with the code to what it currently looks like.  I am getting duplicates for the MFSTNBR.  That appears to be the problem now.  However, I'm not sure how to limit the results at there isn't anything from DB.ACTIVITY_NUM or DB.ACTIVITY_T other than the destination to limit my results which I already have set.  I can't change it to an inner join either as it will eliminate information from other entries that are needed.

Comment: Could you post in your question the records returned from (SELECT MAX(DATE(A.ARRIVEDTS)) as "DERP ARRIVED", MFSTNBR FROM DB.Activity_T A WHERE A.DESTINATION IN ('1234','5647') GROUP BY MFSTNBR) for a specific MFSTNBR  that is returning multiple records.  I just can't see how that would be possible max along with group by shouuld always be one.  I suppose we could add a where where A.ArrivedTS is not null and possibly eliminate the extra record.  But I can't see why max isn't eliminating it.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to format the output of the query so I entered it as code.  I have tried eliminating the null with both a case statement and by entering a where, but that doesn't change the outcome at all.  The only connection I can see is when I add or remove the destination requirement for '1234' and '5647', it changes the nulls to actual data when I remove them, but replaces them with nulls if added.  It's very strange.

Comment: Change the where to `WHERE MNT.DESTINATION IN ('1234','5647') and A.ArrivedTS is not null` perhaps.  I'm at a loss though max and group by should have eliminated those values... I even did some reading [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1740970)   to see if DB2 implemented max the way I think it should and it appears to be standard...   Though... why are you getting 3 columns?  I only had 2 in my query?  date(TS datatype) results in just a date so max of that should result in 1...   Focus on that query to begin with until we're getting 1 row per MFSTNBR we can't move on.

Comment: The 3 columns or two column duplication is the result of the other MFSTNBR for the refnumber.  The very first query I posted here was giving me the ARRIVEDTS without any duplicates.  However, as soon as I added any additional columns from the DB.ACTIVITY_T table it added duplicates.  I ended up just changing it to an inner join to get something in front of my team, but at the expense of losing anything not going to one of the two locations specified.  A small price to pay for the end result, but in a perfect world I could have both.  I'm at a loss...

Comment: I think I've got it narrowed down to how I can eliminate the duplicates since it's coming from the MFSTNBR in the DB.ACTIVITY_NUM table.  That is the source of my duplicates but there is no rhyme or reason to the table to easily pinpoint the one I needs.  However, it works in the same manner by which I was trying to limit results by the MAX(ARRIVEDTS).  There is a UPTS in DB.ACTIVITY_NUM that if I could limit it to the max timestamp then I would be golden.  The problem is I don't know how to get to that result...